# Checking if String has unique values

Tags: java

I have a small function which checks if the given String has all 0's. This method would be used quite often and want to know if it's effectively written. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 /*
 * Input parameters: Employee Number
 * Returns true if sum of employee number is greater than 0,
 * else false.
 */
private boolean employeeNumberCheck(String employeeNumber){
    try{
        if(employeeNumber.length()==0){
            return false;
        }
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<employeeNumber.length();i++){
            counter=counter+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(employeeNumber.charAt(i)));
        }
        if(counter==0)
            return false;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception someException){
        logger.info("Error from method employeeNumberCheck.\n"+someException);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title does not match the problem statement, which does not match the JavaDoc, which in turn does not match the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I would go the regex route. Your code is basically saying: *Anything that parses as a digit is fine, just so long as everything is a digit, and at least one of them is not zero.*

Express that as a regular expression:

```
private static final Pattern validEmployeeNumber = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$");
```

Then your function becomes:

```
private static final Pattern validEmployeeNumber = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$");

private static boolean employeeNumberCheck(String employeeNumber){
    return validEmployeeNumber.matcher(employeeNumber).matches();
}
```

See it [running in ideone](https://ideone.com/cFnHVu)

Comment: A more literal interpretation into regex, and possibly more clear, uses a positive lookahead: `/(?=.*[1-9])\d+/`

Comment: because it is `match`, you don't need the `^` and `$`.

Comment: To be clearer I'd use two simpler regexes. One for isEmployeeNumber : `^[0-9]*$` and One for invalidEmployeeNumbers : `^0*$`.

The check would then be `return isEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber) && ! isInvalidEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber)`

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Good point but the first regex should be `[0-9]+` to require at least one digit.

Answer (score 5):

#### Redundant logic

The initial

> ```
> if (employeeNumber.length() == 0) {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

is not needed. If the string is empty, your loop will never execute and `counter` will be 0 after it, so the code would `return` `false` anyway.

#### Performance

This code

> ```
> counter = counter + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(employeeNumber.charAt(i)));
> ```

is a very expensive and convoluted way to check whether `employeeNumer` has a decimal digit at position `i`.

I'd use something like this instead.

```
final char c = employeeNumber.charAt(i);
if ((c < '0') || (c > '9')) {
    return false;
}
counter += c - '0';  // Add numerical value of the character
```

This works because Java's strings are Unicode and your input only allows digits anyway.

#### Error Handling

You should almost never do this:

> ```
> catch (Exception someException) {
>     …
> }
> ```

What kind of exception do you expect to be `throw`n from within your `try` block? The only possibility I can see is a `NumberFormatException` if `Integer.parseInt` is given something that is not an integer representation. Any other exception you'll `catch` will be camouflaging some serious problem.

- A bug in your own code, such as an indexing error in the iteration over the characters of the string.
- Misuse by your clients, for example, passing in `null` as `employeeNumber`.
- Serious errors in the run-time environment (unlikely in this case).

You shouldn't `catch` any of these.

If you omit the `Integer.parseInt` call as suggested above, there won't be any need for a `try { … } catch { … }` at all any more, which is a good thing.

#### Code formatting

Consider using more spaces even where they are not strictly required lexically.  Most people will find

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeeNumber.length(); i++) {
```

easier to read than

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<employeeNumber.length();i++){
> ```

and it is pretty much agreed upon style.

Also try to be consistent with your use of braces for single statements. Currently, you are sometimes using braces around the single statement of a control-flow construct…

> ```
> if(employeeNumber.length()==0){
>     return false;
> }
> ```

…and sometimes you are not.

> ```
> if(counter==0)
>     return false;
> ```

I don't really care which style you're using but it should be consistent. From what I can tell, most Java programmers seem to prefer to always use braces, even when not strictly required.

Answer (score 2):

Some points:

### Formatting

Your formatting is a bit hard to read. I have fixed it for you, but keep in mind of these standard Java Convention rules:

- Space before `{`
- Space after `if`, `while`, `do`, `for` etc.
- Space surrounding operators (`==`, `=`, etc.)
- Space after `;` in `for` loops

### Bad Practices

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (Exception someException) {
    // logging here
}
```

It is often bad practice to catch every single exception in one catch block, especially if the exceptions can be predicted. In this case, we have `NullPointerException` and `NumberFormatException`.

First, we can identify where and why these exceptions can be thrown, and if they can be prevented.

The `NullPointerException` can be thrown on the first line of your `try` block because `employeeNumber` can be `null`. You can prevent this by doing:

- Throw a `NullPointerException` up the stack
- Return `false` as result
- Log the error, and do one of the above

The `NumberFormatException` can be thrown at `Integer.parseInt()`. You now can just use your original approach, but catch the specific exception:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (NumberFormatException someException) {
    // logging here
}
```

### Misc

Here:

> ```
>     if(counter==0)
>         return false;
>     return true;
> ```

You can just do:

```
    return counter != 0;
```

But most of my complaints (apart from the Exceptions) now don't really apply to the new answer that @rolfl has given. Just keep in mind of these things when writing some other code!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing about loop: you can use a fast enumeration and get rid of the `i` variable:

```
 for (char c : employeeNumber.toCharArray()) {
      // ...
 }
```

Then, `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(employeeNumber.charAt(i)))` is not readable nor efficient.

You can replace it by:

```
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    counter += Character.getNumericalValue(c);
} else {
    // Either throw an exception or return immediately
}
```